Rotate each instance in specific direction
I created a hexagon with a circle curve. Then I instanced arrows on each point. I want to rotate each arrow to point along the edge of the hexagon. How would I do that? A similar question was asked here but the Align Euler and Rotate Euler node is deprecated and using the Rotate rotation node does not allow me to restrict the rotation to only the z-axis


Use the "align euler" node.

Align Euler is depricated

Sorry, I meant "align rotation".

Use align rotation to vector taking from the curve tangent.
But since the tangent on the points is interpolated, the arrows will be between each side.
So we sample a factor (which goes from 0 to 1), where we divide the point index by 6 sides, and add 1/12 to reach the middle of the side.
(Multiply the tangent by -1 to invert)
PS: these cones are pointing to Z, if your arrow is not pointing to Z, change the axis in "align rotation".

